How to access GCP Secret Manager in a .NET application with a proxy configured?
I have a .NET application hosted on Google Cloud Run that needs to access the GCP Secret Manager. My application works fine without a proxy, but when I set a proxy using environment variables (http_proxy or https_proxy), I get the following error when trying to access the Secret Manager:
StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: Unable to get subchannel from HttpRequestMessage. (internet.cp.fd.com:24)
InvalidOperationException: Unable to get subchannel from HttpRequestMessage."

Things I’ve Tried:
Setting NO_PROXY Environment Variable:

I set NO_PROXY to bypass the proxy for secretmanager.googleapis.com, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

I tried clear the  proxy environment variable as null in c# while calling the controller but no luck


How can I properly configure my .NET application to access GCP Secret Manager while respecting the proxy for other HTTP calls, or explicitly disabling the proxy for gRPC calls to GCP?
